# CakePHP controller/action question with http://mysite.com/mycontroller/absentaction

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Suppose someone hits in url http://mysite.com/comments/view/13

But that absentaction is not present in comments controller.

Then it gets normal error like that =>

```
 Error:  The action view is not defined in controller CommentsController

Error: Create CommentsController::view() in file: app/controllers/comments_controller.php.

<?php
class CommentsController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Comments';


    function view() {

    }

}
?>

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/views/errors/missing_action.ctp
```

What i'm trying to do is that if someone hits url http://mysite.com/comments/view/13 and if the action is not present then it will redirect to http://mysite.com/.

How can i do this for unknown/absent action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This trick is actually working pretty well.
You need to create a file app/app_error.php

```
 <?php


class AppError extends ErrorHandler {

    public function error404($params){
        extract($params);

        if(!isset($url)){
            $url = $action;
        }

        if(!isset($message)){
            $message ="";
        }

        if(!isset($base)){
            $base = "";
        }

        $this->controller->redirect(array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'home'));
        //Or the page you want...

    }

}


?>
```

How does it work?

It actually override the `error404()` function from the ErrorHandler and redirect the user whith `$this->controller->redict()`;

Comment: See [the CakePHP API](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/error-handler) for more details

Comment: I just used this=>  <?php


class AppError extends ErrorHandler {
function missingAction($params){
  $this->controller->redirect(array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'index'));    
    }
}
?>   and it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Notice at the bottom of the error message, it says you can customize it by creating `app/views/errors/missing_action.ctp`. So all you need to do is create that .ctp file and include a redirect in it like this:

```
<?php
header( 'Location: http://mysite.com' ) ;
?>
```

Comment: No, i won't create that view and action. Actually you can't create infinite view and action. An user can hit url with any action that is not created.

Comment: @guru You misunderstood: What Brian suggests is that if you create the `missing_action.ctp` file with a redirect you will get the functionality you want.

Comment: So should i create empty view/error/view.ctp ? And should i create ErrorController ?

Comment: @Guru No, you don't need to do that. Whenever a user tries to navigate to any page missing an action, cake will automatically send them to the file `app/views/errors/missing_action.ctp` It has nothing to do with the name of the controller or action.

Comment: @Brian Glaz, so how can i call 'posts/index' when an missing action will occur ? I don't want to use header('...'); is there any cakephp function ?

Comment: if you don't want to use header, you can use the answer provided by @Franquis

Answer (score 0):

It says it right in the error...

> create app/views/errors/missing_action.ctp

And that's what you should do...

Try using a header in the `missing_action.ctp` to redirect to where you want the page to go.

Comment: Can't understand , what do you mean by using header for missing action ?

Answer (score 0):

You can either customise app/views/errors/missing_action.ctp or you can turn off debugging in app/config/core.php

Comment: Which line to change ? What will be the value ?